# How do I "undo an undo" in git?

Tags: git

To reset my last commit, I did this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

But I did it too many times. Now I want to go back forward a couple. Is that possible?

Also, I had a developer pull and merge code on a production application that completely hosed up everything. Then to fix it, he manually overwrote some files in the app source. There are bad commits. The applications is not functioning.

Is there some way to do a hard reset to a particular point in time in Git? I am not familiar enough with it.

Comment: What are you doing? Why don't you ask a new question rather than change your question completely??

Comment: I'm really sorry manojlds, I ran up against my 6 in 24 hours and my emergency was just escalated big time.

Comment: I am not allowed by StackOverflow to ask more than 6 in 24 hours. I ran up against my limit. That's why I had to change my last question.

Comment: I am desperate to get an answer to the question that you just un-edited.

Comment: You can edit it and append the question right? And the answer to that one would be similar. No need to just wipe out the entire question.

Comment: Added answer for the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `git reflog` to see where you were and reset to that. (or use notation like `HEAD@{1}` in reset )

For the other issue, from `git log` get the hash of the commit you want to reset to and do `git reset --hard <sha1>`. Or you can even do `git reset --hard HEAD@{1 day ago}` etc. if you wanted to reset to some commit some time in the past. Since you are rewriting history, you will have to do a force push - `git push -f`

Also, why are developers pushing to production? Have gates - CI, testing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to do a hard reset to a particular point in time in Git?

Yes. `git reset --hard <SHA1-id-of-the-commit-you-want-to-hard-reset-to>`

See [here (Undoing in Git - Reset, Checkout and Revert)](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html) for more on `git reset`. To learn the basics of data recovery, please see here: [Data Recovery Section in Chapter 9 of ProGit book](http://progit.org/book/ch9-7.html).

Few more hints on [how to undo things in git](http://progit.org/book/ch2-4.html).